# Can someone explain how this ActionCable code works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

In irb ;

```
server = ActionCable::Server::Base.new
server.broadcast "channel", message
```

This all works as I would expect it to, sends a message. I am confused as to why it actually works at all. From what I am understanding, `ActionCable::Server::Base` includes `ActionCable::Server::Broadcasting` module which basically allows access to the nested class Broadcasting and from there we basically send a request to the worker pool via pubsub to run the broadcast from the available worker pool which just again schedules another worker?

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/36c1591bcb5e0ee3084759c7f42a706fe5bb7ca7/actioncable/lib/action_cable/server/broadcasting.rb

Comment: What part is confusing? The only thing I can discern is that maybe you aren't fully aware of how `Module` inclusion works in Ruby based on this statement *"allows access to the nested class Broadcasting"*. When you include a Module that Module is injected into the including Class' ancestral chain and the instance methods of the included Module are now accessible to instances of the including Class instances

Comment: Conceptually, once broadcast is called, it uses the configured pubsub adapter to publish a message that all currently-connected websocket connections which are subscribed to the topic will receive. The mechanics of the publish/subscribe depend on your adapter. The worker pool aspect is, I believe, an implementation detail that Rails uses to do the work in the background rather than block the caller thread. Example broadcast implementation for Redis: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/36c1591bcb5e0ee3084759c7f42a706fe5bb7ca7/actioncable/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb#L26

Comment: @RobertNubel my aim is to send a different type tag other than 'message' in the broadcast. Using transmit on channel subscribe I was able to but am struggling to do so with broadcasting. I wanted to see the mechanics of how the transmission is performed to assignment them for my use. Any ideas?